# Editing Functionality in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am Fairly New to AngularJs, I have done crud operations in AngularJs, I have fetched all the records of user having options like(View, Edit(Update), Delete)

If the User Wants To Update the record then he clicked on edit then shows his/her record. all fields are mandatory. if users deletes the text in the Text-box. then press on cancel button it redirects to mange users page with empty field

Like in my plunker, I want to update one record, Clicked on Edit and then in the name(textbox) make it as blank. Immediately click on Cancel
Then Output will be empty of my record(name field)

But, I want data in user record(name field), if user make it as blank

I was Updated My code in here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <div ng-app="userApp" data-ng-controller="userController" class="container">
            <div ng-show="error"  class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <p>{{ error }}</p>
            </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="userModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" ng-hide="editMode">Add User</h4>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel" ng-show="editMode">Edit User</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="adduserform">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="user.name" name="name" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Your Name" required title="Enter your name" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="user.address" name="address" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Your Address" required title="Enter your address" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ContactNo</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" data-ng-model="user.contact" name="contact" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Your ContactNo" required title="Enter your contactno" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                        <span data-ng-hide="editMode">
                                            <input type="submit" value="Add" ng-disabled="adduserform.$invalid" data-ng-click="add()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                    </span>
                                        <span data-ng-show="editMode">
                                            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Update" ng-disabled="" data-ng-click="update()" class="btn btn-primary"/> -->
                                            <input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="update" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <h1>Users List</h1>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <tr>
                    <th>User ID</th>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Contact No</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>

                <tr data-ng-repeat="user in users">
                    <td><strong>{{ user.id }}</strong></td>
                    <td>
                        <p>{{ user.name }}</p>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>{{ user.address }}</p>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>{{ user.contact }}</p>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>
                            <a data-ng-click="get(user)" href="javascript:;">View</a> |
                            <a data-ng-click="edit(user)" href="javascript:;">Edit</a> |
                            <a data-ng-click="showconfirm(user)" href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
                        </p>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <hr />

            <div class="modal fade" id="viewModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View User</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="viewuser">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        {{user.name}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Address" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        {{user.address}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ContactNo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">ContactNo</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        {{user.contact}}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal fade" id="confirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm Action</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            Are you sure to delete?
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="delete()">Ok</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

please help me out with this situation

Comment: I think this is a good question, but to attract the right people: improve your English (start your sentences with a capital letter for instance), don't suppose everybody knows _Plunker_, if possible, paste the most relevant fragment of code here (intended and separated, so it looks like code) etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding your modal to the original user object.

Instead you can make a temporary copy of the user, and if you click cancel, copy the temp back to the original user:

```
$scope.edit = function () {

    $scope.user = this.user;
    $scope.tempUser = angular.copy($scope.user); //copy user to temp
    $scope.editMode = true;
    $('#userModel').modal('show');
};

$scope.cancel = function () {
    angular.copy($scope.tempUser, $scope.user); // copy back from temp to user
    $('#userModel').modal('hide');
}
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9CqpKLwblYiQVFlQTtHy?p=preview)

Comment: @ user3906922..This is Exactly What I am looking for.. Thank You much.